# Downloading Multiple Parts Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

I am new to Android development and want to download multiple (infact too many) chunks of a file but downloading all those with code written with my bare hands are not good way.

Is there any good Downloading library for Android Studio ?

The downloading links are not different for chunks.
Such as

```
https://link.com/path/download_1.chunk
https://link.com/path/download_2.chunk
```

Any code direction too would be great.

Comment: Please show us your efforts ! What have you attempted ?

Comment: @Madhur if i know I would. Please help me with this. Plus I need to convert those chunk into a single pack as MP4 too. Have no idea

Answer (score 0):

I would use a web browser to download files that are chunked as opposed to Android Studio.

If the question is how to download these files in your app, then I would use either the [DownloadManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager) for downloading large files or use [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) for all networking requests.

Comment: @Brain The main question has a tag of Android Studio that makes it clear that developer wants to download those chunks in their app :)

Comment: Any retrofit code example would be great. This how the file looks which contains the info about the chunks https://justpaste.it/7fpe3